# How can I take screenshots from a background process?

Tags: c#, windows, screenshot

I want to set up a system whereby anyone logged onto a machine on our local network can see what's on the screen of any other machine on the local network. This is part of a peer-monitoring programme, and is with the agreement of all users.

All machines are running Windows 7 or 10. Ideally, I would like it that someone using an iPad could also see the screens.

My initial thought was to install IIS on each machine, and have a web site that would capture the screen and return it on request. That way, a user at another machine could just browse to http://machinename/ and see the screenshots. This would work for desktop machines and iPads.

However, I discovered that you can't access the screen that way, so that idea is out. Similarly, it seems that a Windows service can't access the screen either.

What options do I have? I want something that can be installed once for all users, and show what's on the screen(s) attached to that machine.

Comment: There are several screen capture libraries out there. All of them use either DirectX (/DirectShow) or native Win32 API calls to do the job. I did not come across any other solution yet.

Comment: @Psi Do you know of any specific ones? I'm not sure what to look for. Also, wouldn't they have the same problem as I had, that the background process can't access the screen? Thanks for the reply

Comment: @Psi Any suggestions? Anyone else? I've searched and searched, but can't find anything that doesn't rely on Graphics.FromImage(), which throws an exception when run in the background (ie in an MVC controller method or in a Windows service)

Comment: Google for "Windows Screen Capturing", you'll find tons of examples. And maybe google for "marshalling c#". And using IIS for that purpose is like using a microwave to paintbrush an elephant oO. With c# you can write Desktop applications. However, maybe you'll find VNC handy

Comment: @Psi I think you misunderstood me. I know how to capture the screen in C#. I also know how to marshal C#, but don't see how it's relevant to my question. As for IIS, I know it's OTT, but if you can suggest a simpler way that fits my requirements, please do so. Note that a desktop app is NOT suitable, as this needs to be something installed once per machine that will run for all users, and not something I have to set up for each user. It also has to be able to be called without the user knowing. That's why I thought of IIS or a background process. VNC is just as OTT as IIS, and more intrusive

Comment: The main problem why services can't capture the screen is simply because they are not attached to any windows session. You would need to interact with the nt session manager because the simple question is: Whose screen do you want to capture? There might be multiple session running simultaneously, and only because there is only one of the doesn't mean that in 2 minutes there won't be more of them. You need to attached to a session (e.g. the console foreground session)

Comment: @Psi Thanks, that's the nub of the problem. I want to know how to interact with the sessions. I know there will only ever be one, as these machine don't have any remote access set up, so either no-one will be logged on (in which case the machine will almost certainly be powered down) or exactly one person will be logged on. How do I get at the session?

Comment: Just because there is no remote access doesn't mean there can only be one session (see: switching users). As I mentioned, there will at maximum one foreground console session.

Comment: @Psi So let me ask the question another way. Can I get at that foreground console session and see the screen? That's all I want to do. Thanks again

Comment: A good resource is https://brianbondy.com/blog/100/understanding-windows-at-a-deeper-level-sessions-window-stations-and-desktops, took me 2 minutes to find it using Google.

Comment: @Psi I doubt I would have found that, wasn't the sort of thing I was looking for at all! Anyway, it looks like this is going to be way beyond my current capabilities, and as this was a nice-to-have, I'm not going to have time to invest in learning how to do it. Reading that article, it doesn't look like it's going to be simple anyway. Thanks for the help.

Comment: That's what I expected. Teams spend months and years to make this kind of services work. Don't expect it to be done within a couple of days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like a lot of similar questions out there, a simple solution requires just some basic understanding of how Windows session isolation works, detailed in [posts like this](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-performance-team/application-compatibility-session-0-isolation/ba-p/372361).

As you want to capture screenshots, your code must run in the same user session. Then any sample code you find from search engines will work flawlessly.

Many existing screen capture solutions are built upon this simple approach, and usually have a Windows tray app that launches when a user logs in, which prepares the screen shots by calling the capture API.

> You cannot use a Windows service or a web app on IIS to call the capture API, because they run in session 0, not that user session.

Behind the scene, other necessary components are there to dispatch the screen shots to a centralized backend server (so that they can then be sent to the monitoring device).

> Note that for this part multiple approaches/architectures can be used, so I won't share too much to restrict your imagination.